# Magento Login C# and Soap V2 v1.9

Tags: c#, magento, magento-1.9

I have a C# interface that connects to magento Api, I am using SOAP. This used to work fine, but recently cannot login. To simplify I just put the connection code here:

```
handler = new MagentoApi.Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortTypeClient(); var endpoint = handler.Endpoint;

string username = "xxxxxxxx";
string apiKey = "xxxxxxxx";

var credentions = handler.ClientCredentials;

session = handler.login(username, apiKey);

if (session != null )
lblConnected.Text = "Connected";
```

On `handler.login(username, apiKey);` I am getting an exception:

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

and Exception message is

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I talked to hosting company and they told me that nothing has changed and the service is not blocked.

Comment: The 403 http status code is a server side one, which means that is not the hosting of your web app but the remote hosting (the magneto service endpoint) who is failing to admit those credentials.

Check this link for all the status codes for more info https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1w63wjr_RAhVEuxQKHXvQADUQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FProtocols%2Frfc2616%2Frfc2616-sec10.html&usg=AFQjCNGzqxVrtXtzSUw8D0_Ax350CEUUig&sig2=nR93qswbRKKL9OCCxtOntA

Comment: In your code, you are setting a user and password, but the remote server response detects a Anonymous request and failing because of that. I havent used magneto, but I guess you have configured the service configuration somewhere. Try to edit your question and provide the service configuration (avoiding the confidential info)